# Setting up a Step Definition in Ruby from a Scenario Outline

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

I have the following Step Outline which I have started using and constructed in the following format:

## Step Definition

```
@web1
Scenario Outline: A teacher filters the report
Given I am signed in as a teacher
And I navigate to the reports page
Then I click on the School Overview report
And I select an <option> from the dropdown

Examples:
    |option| 
    |teacher|
    |subject|
    |class|
    |year|
```

### What I want to Achieve

For each of the options, I want a different dropdown option to be selected (the logic for which I have defined in the step definition already) so that instead of creating multiple scenarios for the similar actions, I can group them together above.

Previously the same step definition was used where I had multiple scenarios doing the same thing - opening one dropdown after another. Now, however I'm not sure how I can setup the step definition file for this .. this is what I have tried experimenting with:

```
And(/^I select an <option> from the dropdown$/) do |table|
    table.raw.each do |report_filter_types|

        if report_filter_types.eql?("teacher")
             # Making the teacher selection from the dropdown by selecting the first option
           # @wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => '.container-fluid > .filter-bar-element:nth-of-type(1) > .ember-view > .ember-view.ember-basic-dropdown-trigger > span:nth-of-type(1)').click}
            #@wait.until {@driver.current_url.include?('teacher=')}
        elsif report_filter_types.eql?("subject")
            # Making the subject selection from the dropdown by selecting the first option
            @wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => '.container-fluid > .filter-bar-element:nth-of-type(2)').click} 
            @wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => '.ember-view.ember-basic-dropdown-trigger > span:nth-of-type(1)').click}
            @wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => '.ember-basic-dropdown-content > .ember-view > li:nth-of-type(1)').click}
        elsif report_filter_types.eql?("class")
            # Making the classes selection from the dropdown by expanding it and then choosing the first option
            @wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => '.container-fluid > .filter-bar-element:nth-of-type(3) > .ember-view > .ember-view.ember-basic-dropdown-trigger > span:nth-of-type(1)').click}
            @wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => 'a.ember-view.grouped-classes-options').click}
            @wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => '.ember-view > li:nth-of-type(1) > .ember-view > li:nth-of-type(1) > .ember-view > li').click}
        elsif report_filter_types.eql?("year")
            # Making a year selection from the dropdown by expanding it and choosing the first option
            @wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => '.last > span:nth-of-type(1)').click}
            @wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => '.ember-basic-dropdown-content > .ember-view > li:nth-of-type(1)').click}
        end
        puts "Report filtered by #{report_filter_types}"
    end
end
```

The part where it says `report_filter_types` is simply where I have defined the action that needs to take place for selecting each 'individual' dropdown in the application. Not sure how I can connect this to the table!

The code above is setup in the the format where I would have separate 'scenario' for opening each dropdown, however i want to utilise the existing code above, tweak it and use a table format to make it neater and easier to maintain this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep things simple instead write

```
Background:
  Given I am signed in as a teacher
  And I navigate to the reports page
  And I click on the School Overview report

Scenario: Filter on option
  When I filter on option

When "I filter on option" do
  ...
end
```

Write a scenario for each option

You will find you end up with less code, and much much simpler step definitions.

Also note that your example does not have a `Then` after the `When`. The point of the scenario surely is to write an expectation of what should happen after you filter on the option.

In general avoid scenario outlines you can Cuke simply and with great power without ever using them.

Comment: Thanks @diabolist! Yeah I think I will avoid using the Outlines as it's going to cause me more headaches! Best used for more simple things!